# how to create a query with geolocation in mongoose (use for search by near places)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm quite new in mongodb and mongoose. I don't know if my query is working but when I add some geojson to my code it returns null.
My only target is can filter my data using state,country and state and also search nearby places. It would be really great help if someone can help me. Thanks

```
var query = {
  $and : [
  {city : new RegExp('^'+req.body.city+'$', "i") },
  {state : req.body.state},
  {country : req.body.country},
    {
      loc : {
      $nearSphere : {
        $geometry : {
          type : "Point",
          coordinates : [-117.16108380000003,32.715738]
        },
        $maxDistance : 100
      }
    }
  }
Business.find(query).populate('deal_id').sort({business_type : -1,deal_id : -1})
.exec(function(err,businesses){
  res.json(businesses)
  return
})
```

I don't know if im doing it right, here's my sample data:

```
[
{
    "_id": "5a0b1f489929442c36fd5c83",
    "business_row": 29160,
    "created_at": "2017-11-14T16:52:10.130Z",
    "owner_name": "David Lui",
    "company_website": "",
    "phone_number": "604-273-3288",
    "contact_name": "David Lui",
    "zip_postal": "V6X 3Z9",
    "state": "British Columbia",
    "country": "Canada",
    "city": "Richmond",
    "address": "3779 Sexsmith Rd # 2172 Richmond British Columbia",
    "company_name": "Aem Seafood",
    "__v": 1,
    "slug": "Aem-Seafood&Richmond",
    "loc": {
        "coordinates": [
            "-123.129488",
            "49.185359"
        ],
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "deal_id": [],
    "is_favorite": false,
    "is_draft": false,
    "has_featured": false,
    "owner_id": [
        "5a0adcf9f7205f0004535def"
    ],
    "files": [],
    "operations": [],
    "sub_category": [],
    "category_options": [
        {
            "value": "5a0b186b9f3a4a2710075654",
            "sub_cat": {
                "value": "59f6d13d00086a6e645c50a4",
                "label": "Meat And Fish Markets"
            }
        }
    ],
    "category_id": [
        "5a0b186b9f3a4a2710075654"
    ],
    "business_type_name": "Free",
    "business_type": "0",
    "user_id": [
        "5a0adcf9f7205f0004535def"
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

turns out i don't need to query the city,state and country for it and use $geoWithIn